# Trouble with anomaly/novelty detection (on microscale) - need easy practical guide with Keras

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, autoencoder, image-recognition

I am relatively new to the field of machine learning. However, I already have solved simple image classification tasks with Keras (for example building CNNs and classifying MNIST...). The rough deep learning concepts (CNN, RNN, Autoencoder) are clear to me.

Now, I am trying to solve a practical task with Keras: Recognizing little artifacts/defects/anomalies on images - for example see following images.

[image: springer.com]

My plan is to train an Autoencoder only with "good images" without any anomalies. After I feed the Autoencoder with "bad" images (with artefacts, defects) and compare the output of the Autoencoder with the input image, I hope to get a similarity score which tells me that this is an image with anomalies.

I also have done some research:

- https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/image-anomaly-detection-using-autoencoders-ae937c7fd2d1
- https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/10/23/8660/pdf
- ...

The first article feels a little bit rough. Comparing clothes with numbers is not the same as finding anomalies on a micro-scale. The second one is very complex without any code example.

The image size is $512x256$ and the artifacts can be tiny. I have more than 50,000 "good" images.

I played around with the architecture and the parameters. Firstly, I tried to build a CNN-Autoencoder with more features (middle of Autoencoder), but the problem here is that I always reproduce the anomalies as well. Secondly, I reduced the number of features (in middle of the Autoencoder), but then I only get a blurred output without any details of the image.

So I feel I need a better starting point (practical guide) to build my autoencoder --> which detailed architecture, loss-function,...???

Maybe I am completely on the wrong track and an Autoencoder is not the right tool?

Following a code example of my autoencoder:

```
height_image = 256 
width_image = 512
channels_image = 1
inputshape = (height_image, width_image, channels_image)

POOL_SIZE = (2,2)
FILTERS = 32
KERNEL_SIZE = (3,3)


input_img = Input(shape=inputshape)

x = Conv2D(FILTERS, KERNEL_SIZE, activation="relu", padding="same")(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D(POOL_SIZE, padding="same")(x)
x = Conv2D(FILTERS*2, KERNEL_SIZE, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(32, POOL_SIZE, padding="same")(x)
x = Conv2D(FILTERS*4, KERNEL_SIZE, activation="relu", padding="same", activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-5))(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(POOL_SIZE, padding="same")(x)

x = Conv2D(FILTERS*4, KERNEL_SIZE, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = UpSampling2D(POOL_SIZE)(x)
x = Conv2D(FILTERS*2, KERNEL_SIZE, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = UpSampling2D(POOL_SIZE)(x)
x = Conv2D(FILTERS, KERNEL_SIZE, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
x = UpSampling2D(POOL_SIZE)(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, KERNEL_SIZE, activation="sigmoid", padding="same")(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
    
autoencoder.compile(optimizer="adam", loss= 'binary_crossentropy')
```

Thanks.